# How to sort a HashMap by value but keep the order of duplicates?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I'm trying to sort the `tableProbability` map into a new one called `sorted`. In `tableProbability` the values are the following:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| M | 0.1 |
| U | 0.3 |
| L | 0.3 |
| T | 0.2 |
| I | 0.1 |

I have the following code that sorts the `Map`:

```java
LinkedHashMap<Character, Double> sorted = new LinkedHashMap<>();
tableProbability.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .forEachOrdered(x -> sorted.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
```

But what I end up getting is the following `Map`:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| L | 0.3 |
| U | 0.3 |
| T | 0.2 |
| I | 0.1 |
| M | 0.1 |

And what I am supposed to get is:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| U | 0.3 |
| L | 0.3 |
| T | 0.2 |
| M | 0.1 |
| I | 0.1 |

Is there any way to retain the duplicate order or at least when it finds a duplicate to put it past the one with the equal value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, but you can simplify it as follows:

1. Source map:

   ```java
   LinkedHashMap<Character, Double> tableProbability =
           new LinkedHashMap<>() {{
               put('M', 0.1);
               put('U', 0.3);
               put('L', 0.3);
               put('T', 0.2);
               put('I', 0.1);
           }};
   ```

   ```java
   System.out.println(tableProbability);
   // {M=0.1, U=0.3, L=0.3, T=0.2, I=0.1}
   ```
2. This code works fine:

   ```java
   LinkedHashMap<Character, Double> sorted = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   tableProbability.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
           .forEachOrdered(x -> sorted.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
   ```

   ```java
   System.out.println(sorted);
   // {U=0.3, L=0.3, T=0.2, M=0.1, I=0.1}
   ```
3. Simplified version:

   ```java
   LinkedHashMap<Character, Double> sorted2 = tableProbability
           .entrySet().stream()
           .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
           .collect(LinkedHashMap::new,
                   (col, e) -> col.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()),
                   HashMap::putAll);
   ```

   ```java
   System.out.println(sorted2);
   // {U=0.3, L=0.3, T=0.2, M=0.1, I=0.1}
   ```

---

<sup>See also: [Ordering Map<String, Integer> by List<String> using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66245618/14940971)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do it this way.  It is common operation.  If you want to return a `TreeMap`, you can specify it below.  And normally one assigns to the interface type.  For a `TreeMap` it would be `NavigableMap`.

```
Map<Character, Double> sorted =
        tableProbability.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
                        Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                        Entry::getValue,
                        (a,b)->a, // merge, not used here but
                                  // syntactically required
                        LinkedHashMap::new // type of map to return
                        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a compound comparator:

```
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .andThen(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
)
```