# Ordering Map<String, Integer> by List<String> using streams

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-stream, treemap

```java
Map<String, Integer> nonOrderedData = // {b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4, a=0}
List<String> orderSequence = // a, b, c, d, e
```

I need to apply the order sequence to get correctly ordered data, how could I achieve this using (prefered) stream?

What I used is non stream way:

```java
Map<String, Integer> orderedData = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> nod : nonOrderedData.entrySet()) {
    for (String os : orderSequence) {
        if (os == nod.getKey()) {
            // add nonOrderedData data
        } else {
            // add data by sequence
        }
    }
}
```

Would like to have more cleaner way of what I want.

---

I've noticed that in my method I could just return `new TreeMap<>(nonOrderedData)` and it would work just fine, but I don't want to stick to just applying asc order - I would like to read actual sequence values and then change `nonOrderedData`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HashMap` cannot be used to store `orderedData` because it does not guarantee ordering of its keys, so `LinkedHashMap` should be used which maintains insertion order.

Ordering by the data presented in `orderSequence` using streams may be implemented in two modes:

1. Keep only the values available in `nonOrderedData`:

```java
Map<String, Integer> nonOrderedData = Map.of(
    "b", 1, "e", 4, "a", 0, "o", 5, "d", 7
);
List<String> orderSequence = Arrays.asList(
    "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "b", "c", "d"
);

Map<String, Integer> reordered = orderSequence
    .stream()
    .filter(nonOrderedData::containsKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        key -> key, nonOrderedData::get, 
        (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
    
System.out.println(reordered);
```

**Output:**

```
{a=0, e=4, o=5, b=1, d=7}
```

It is similar to `INNER JOIN` between `orderSequence` and `nonOrderedData`.

2. Filling `reorderedData` with some default value if the key from `orderSequence` is missing in `nonOrderedData`:

```java
Map<String, Integer> reorderedWithDefault = orderSequence
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        key -> key, nonOrderedData.getOrDefault(key, -1), 
        (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
    
System.out.println(reorderedWithDefault);
```

**Output:**

```
{a=0, e=4, i=-1, o=5, u=-1, b=1, c=-1, d=7}
```

It is similar to `LEFT JOIN` between `orderSequence` and `nonOrderedData`.

---

**Update**
In the above-mentioned implementations the key-value pairs in `nonOrderedData` that do not match to the keys in `orderSequence` are skipped altogether.  Such keys may be tracked (and added later to the `reordered` result) using [`Map::remove (Object key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) which returns a value of the key being removed.

*However, the following two code examples modify the state of `nonOrderedData` outside the stream execution.*

1. Keep the keys and related values *only* from `nonOrderedData`, place the non-matched pairs to the end:

```java
Map<String, Integer> nonOrderedData = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
    "b", 1, "e", 4, "z", 8, "a", 0, "q", 6,
    "f", 5, "d", 7
    ));
List<String> orderSequence = Arrays.asList("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "b", "c", "d");

Map<String, Integer> reordered = orderSequence
    .stream()
    .filter(nonOrderedData::containsKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        key -> key, nonOrderedData::remove, 
        (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new
    ));

SortedMap<String, Integer> remainder = new TreeMap<>(nonOrderedData);
System.out.println("remained: " + remainder);
    
reordered.putAll(remainder);

System.out.println(reordered);
```

**Output:**

```
remained: {f=5, q=6, z=8}
{a=0, e=4, b=1, d=7, f=5, q=6, z=8}
```

It is similar to `RIGHT JOIN` between `orderSequence` and `nonOrderedData`.

2. Keep all values from both `orderSequence` and `nonOrderedData` similar to `FULL JOIN`

Here default values will be provided for the non-mapped keys in `orderSequence` and non-matched keys from `nonOrderedData` will be added to the end.

```java
Map<String, Integer> reorderedFull = orderSequence
    .stream()
    .peek(key -> nonOrderedData.computeIfAbsent(key, (k) -> -1)) // default value
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        key -> key, nonOrderedData::remove, 
        (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new
    ));

SortedMap<String, Integer> remainderFull = new TreeMap<>(nonOrderedData);
System.out.println("remained: " + remainderFull);
    
reorderedFull.putAll(remainderFull);
System.out.println(reorderedFull);
```

**Output:**

```
remained: {f=5, q=6, z=8}
{a=0, e=4, i=-1, o=-1, u=-1, b=1, c=-1, d=7, f=5, q=6, z=8}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have *an ordered sequence*, you can collect a new map with *keys* from that sequence and *values* from the *unordered map* using the [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) method, which *removes the mapping for a key* from that map and returns *the previous value*.

After collecting a new map, if there is something left in the *unordered map*, you can add those entries using [`putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) method.

```java
Map<String, Integer> nonOrderedData = new HashMap<>(
        Map.of("f", 5, "b", 1, "c", 2, "d", 3, "e", 4, "a", 0));

List<String> orderSequence = List.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
```

```java
Map<String, Integer> orderedMap = orderSequence.stream()
        .collect(LinkedHashMap::new,
                (col, e) -> col.put(e, nonOrderedData.remove(e)),
                HashMap::putAll);
```

```java
System.out.println(orderedMap); // {a=0, b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4}
System.out.println(nonOrderedData); // {f=5}

orderedMap.putAll(nonOrderedData); // add what's left

System.out.println(orderedMap); // {a=0, b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4, f=5}
```

---

Similarly, instead of a *map* you can collect a *list of map entries*:

```java
Map<String, Integer> nonOrderedData = new HashMap<>(
        Map.of("f", 5, "b", 1, "c", 2, "d", 3, "e", 4, "a", 0));

List<String> orderSequence = List.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
```

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> orderedList = orderSequence.stream()
        .map(e -> Map.entry(e, nonOrderedData.remove(e)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```java
System.out.println(orderedList); // [a=0, b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4]
System.out.println(nonOrderedData); // {f=5}

orderedList.addAll(nonOrderedData.entrySet()); // add what's left

System.out.println(orderedList); // [a=0, b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4, f=5]
```